# C++ pointer of specific bit size

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, bit-fields

My question is about pointing to chunks of memory of an odd size.

Let's say I have a `struct` declared like so:

```
typedef struct{
   int32 val1  : 29; 
   int32 val2  : 26;
   char  val3;
}MyStruct;
```

Let's assume declaring specific bit fields in the struct is desireable (why we'd use the bit fields is not the question).

If I wanted to declare a pointer that points to one of those fields, I might try something like this:

```
MyStruct test;
int32 *myPtr = &(test.val1);
```

Except that this produces the error "*taking the address of a bit field is not allowed*".

Assuming that we would want to, is there a way to point to those fields in this way? I know that C++ will probably pad the fields to the next byte (which in this case would be 32 bits).

Comment: Since pointers "point" to bytes, I would expect this behavior to be normal, as there is no way of storing the address of something that may not be a "complete" byte.

Comment: I don't believe you'll see any padding for bitfield members that have their bit size specified (or at least, you can't be sure of getting any - it's implementation-defined).

Comment: @RichieHindle: indeed, and for most small values, there will be no padding, as this is exactly the reason bitfields were invented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++, the smallest addressable value must have a size of at least 1 byte. So No you cannot take address of an bit field with pointers.

**C++03 Standard 9.6 Bit-fields:**
**Para 3:**

> ...The address-of operator& shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there are no pointers to bit-fields.
>   ....

Answer (score 6):

> Except that this produces the error "taking the address of a bit field is not allowed".

This is explicitly disallowed by the standard. See **[class.bit]** 9.6/3:

> The address-of operator & shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there are no pointers to bitfields.

A byte (which is `CHAR_BIT` bits wide, where `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8) is the minimum you can address.

> Assuming that we would want to, is there a way to point to those fields in this way?

No. You can have a pointer to an object of the enclosing `struct` type though. This is a direct carry over from C; See [C FAQ 2.26](http://c-faq.com/struct/bitfields.html):

> Bit-fields are inconvenient when you also want to be able to manipulate some collection of bits as a whole (perhaps to copy a set of flags).

You may want to look at other alternatives such `std::bitset` or [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get a pointer to a bit field.  If you're willing to
implement an equivalent structure yourself, however, using shifts and
masks, you should be able to define a smart pointer into it.  Something 
like:

```
class BitFieldPointer
{
    unsigned* myData;
    unsigned  myMask;
    unsigned  myShift;

    class DereferenceProxy
    {
        BitFieldPointer const* myOwner;
    public:
        DereferenceProxy(BitFieldPointer const* owner) : myOwner( owner ) {} operator unsigned() const
        {
            return (*myOwner->myData && myOwner->myMask) >> myOwner->myShift;
        }

        void operator=( unsigned new_value ) const
        {
            *myData = (*myOwner->myData && ~myOwner->myMask) |
                    ((new_value << myOwner->myShift) && myOwner->myMask);
        }
    };
public:
    //  ...
    DereferenceProxy operator*() const
    {
        return DereferenceProxy(this);
    }
};
```

(This is just a rough idea.  You'll probably want both a pointer and a
pointer to const, and the lifetime of the proxy vs. that of its owner
may be an issue.)